# If you union Two queries, do we need to run ToList() on each of them first?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have some `LINQ to SQL` queries and want to get the result of their `union`. Do I need to run `ToList()` on each of them first? or I can leave them as `IQueryable` and union them and at the end of union just call one `ToList()` ?  And does this have any performance improvement at all? or it is essentially the same thing?

```
var query1 = ( from a in this.Context.Blah select a); // .ToList()??
var query2 = ( from b in this.Context.Yada select b); // .ToList()??
var query3 = (query1.Union(query2)).ToList();
```

Comment: **And does this have any performance improvement at all? or it is essentially the same thing?**


`ToList()` decreases performance, as it executes the LINQ-to-SQL query ( hitting the database). This will be done 2 times, prior to the real work (the union call).

Not calling `ToList()` until the final query is constructed, you are `deferring execution` (and deferring round trips to the db).

There are certain operations where working with data results in memory is *faster* than having the database operate on it. A good rule of thumb, "whenever possible, let the database do the work."

Comment: This is specific to LINQ-to-XML, however the concept of Lazy Evaluation is important across all LINQ types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scenario 1:**

```
var query1 = ( from a in this.Context.Blah select a); // you have a query
var query2 = ( from b in this.Context.Yada select b); // you have another query
var query3 = (query1.Union(query2)); // you build a new query
var result = query3.ToList(); // you execute a query and get result
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
//this builds a query and execute it and get result from database
var query1 = ( from a in this.Context.Blah select a).ToList(); // you execute a query

//this builds a query and execute it and get result from database
var query2 = ( from b in this.Context.Yada select b).ToList(); // you execute another query

//this builds a query and execute it but it does not hit database because you are working
//with IEnumerable here not IQueryable
var query3 = (query1.Union(query2)); // you build a new query
var result = query3.ToList(); // you execute another query and get result
```

Scenario 2 execute 3 query and have 2 round trips to database while the first one just fetch what you want with one round trip.

There is a lot of difference between building a query and executing it. Calling methods like `ToList`, `ToArray`, `First`, `Single` and ... will execute the query you have built since calling methods like `Where`, `Union`, `Except` and ... are just building up the query for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should let the database union the data sets.  It'll likely be able to do it faster than you can do it, and any items that get removed are items that don't need to be sent to you over the network.

Comment: hmm? From your answers I still don't undersatand do I need to call ToList or not ? Thanks.

Comment: @Bohn Then it sounds like you need to spend some time reading intro LINQ tutorials, and reading the documentation on what methods such as ToList do.